# Border stroke issue with Custom UITextField

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield

I'm customizing a UITextField to be taller and have different border colors and shadows than the default:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.f;
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.f;
    textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:196/255.0 green:111/255.0 blue:3/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = .2f;
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,3);
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 3.f;
    textField.clipsToBounds = NO;

    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
    textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:196/255.0 green:111/255.0 blue:3/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 3.f;

    return YES;
}
```

However, it seems that something is screwing up the rendering of the border in the 'unfocused' state in the bottom left hand:

[image: stroke issue in uitextfield]

Comment: Instead of all this layer stuff, have you already tried a custom transparent textfield over two different background images?

Comment: @ott-- is right - use custom control then do your own bezel using images or code in a drawrect.